# Grep between some period

Tags: linux, logging, grep

I have large log file, in which each record starts with date, formatted like this:

```
[2014-10-06 07:03:49]
```

What`s the easiest way to grep by specific period of time ?

I want to grep by specific date range, for example, taking the example date, from 06.10.2014 to 08.10.2014.

Comment: see: https://github.com/mdom/dategrep

Comment: This is YYYY-MM-DD format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your format is like `[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]`, you have to create some kind of regular expression to cover the dates your are willing to `grep`.

For example, if you just want to filter days from 6 to 8 when year is 2014 and month 10, you can say:

```
grep '^\[2014-10-0[6-8]' file
```

This says: fetch all those lines starting with `[2014-10-0` followed by 6, 7 or 8.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
[2014-10-06 07:03:49] line1
[2014-10-06 07:14:49] line2
[2014-10-06 07:03:49] line3
[2014-10-07 07:03:49] line4
[2014-10-08 07:09:49] line5
[2014-10-09 07:03:49] line6
[2015-01-11 07:03:49] line7
$ grep '^\[2014-10-0[6-8]' a
[2014-10-06 07:03:49] line1
[2014-10-06 07:14:49] line2
[2014-10-06 07:03:49] line3
[2014-10-07 07:03:49] line4
[2014-10-08 07:09:49] line5
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `grep`, I'd use `awk`.

```
awk -v from="[2014-10-20 00:00:00]" -v to="[2015-01-02 23:59:59]" '
    {datetime = $1 " " $2}
    from <= datetime && datetime <= to
' file
```

Congratulations on using a sane, sortable datetime format.